# "Reporting Services Error" in Project Dashboard

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, tfs

Im using TFS 2012, SQL2012, and Sharepoint 2010. I went through the advanced installation of TFS and believe I missed some permission or something with an application pool. Everything related to TFS works well but any time I go to the project dashboard under Task Burndown I see this error:

Reporting Services Error
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) Get Online Help
Query execution failed for dataset 'dsProjectGuid'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) Get Online Help
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
SQL Server Reporting Services

Then under Burn Rate I see this error:
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) Get Online Help
Query execution failed for dataset 'dsProjectGuid'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) Get Online Help
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
SQL Server Reporting Services

I came across [this post](http://davidrbrown.com/2010/04/06/tfs-2010-reporting-services-error-rsinvalidreportparameter/) which seems similar but then I try to actually 
process the database I get an error.

Also, if I go to the TFS Administration Console >> Application Tier >> Reporting, I see the Warehouse database and Analysis database are "Configured and Jobs Enabled".

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you don't mention:

- The OS (Windows Server 2012 or 2008 or 2008 R2 and which SP???)
- SharePoint Foundation or SharePoint Server 2010, is it SharePoint with SP1 or not??
- The error you faced when you manually try to process the warehouse???

Anyway, the reporting errors could be happened because many reasons, so my advice to you, just take a look on my 2 **Guides** about installing TFS 2012 and 2010, see the reporting section, you will know exactly what you should do and how to verify every step before moving to the next one, they have videos and documents with every detail steps needed.

I recommended to have a look on the whole sections because sometimes the error will be in the service account used for configuring the **Report Service** which will exiting on the first section.

[TFS 2012 Guide](http://tfs2012visualguide.codeplex.com/)

[TFS 2010 Guide](http://tfs10enterprise.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @BBauer42: Do you recall which users these were?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_26427476.html

I referred the above link which worked for me.

I set initial catalog for data source TfsReportDS as "Tfs_Warehouse" and the initial catalog for data source TfsOlapReportDS as Tfs_Analysis. Other setting I left it to default which is 'windows Integerated security' for TfsReportDS and 'credentials are not required for Tfs2010OlapReportDS

Jacob